# Unable to load contents while reading a .txt file in Python3

Tags: python

I am intending to extract some data stored in a .txt file using python 3, however, when I tried to print out the file content, the program does not display any thing in the console. This is the code snippet I use to read the file:

```
def get_data(directory):
    entries = os.listdir(directory)
    #print(entries)
    count = 0;
    for file in entries:
        #print(file)
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(file) as curr_file:
                #print(curr_file)
                #read data and write it to an 
                #excel worksheet
                
                print(curr_file.readline())
                curr_file.close()
```

What kind of changes am I supposed to make to let the program display contents of the file?
Update: I tried to print out all files saved in entries and the result looks fine. The following is the code snippet I used to unzip files in the directory, I am not sure whether there're anything wrong with it.

```
def read_zip(path):
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    #print(file_list)
    #create a new directory and store 
    #the extracted file there 
    directory = 'C:/Users/chent/Desktop/Test'
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
            print('Folder created')
    except FileExistsError:
            print ('Directory not created')    
                
    for file in file_list:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            filePath=path+'/'+file
            zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filePath)
            for names in zip_file.namelist():
                zip_file.extract(names, directory)
                
                get_data(directory)                   
            zip_file.close()
```

Solution: It turns out that I didn't specify the file path when use `with open()` statement, which caused the program unable to locate files. To fix it, use `with open(file_path, file, "r") as curr_file`. See details in my updated code:

```
def get_data(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)   
    for file in files:
        #print(file)
        try:
            if file.endswith('.txt'):
                print(file)
                with open('C:/Users/chent/Desktop/Test/' + file, "r", ) as curr_file:
                   # print(curr_file.readlines())
                    print(curr_file)   
                    line = curr_file.readline()
                    print(line)
                    
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print ('File not found')  
    
    
                
path = 'C:/Users/chent/Desktop/Test'
get_data(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `curr_file.readline()` which only returns the first line.

Use `curr_file.read()` to get the whole file contents.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that is the issue cause I tried couple of ways of reading it and they all didn't quite work. I updated the other part of my code. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Is it possible you are reading the file before the data is written? What if you do the unzipping first, and THEN runs the code to read the files?

Comment: I separated my function of reading .txt files and it turns out read nothing in it. The program displays ```[]``` for each of the file when I use ```file.readlines()```.

Comment: I suggest you go step by step over you program and see if the directories and files are as you expect when you initially read the zip, then unzip it, the read it. I tried the `get_data` function locally in a folder that had a ".txt" extension and the contents printed correctly. Also could the file extension be incorrect (some whitespoace after the `.txt` or something?)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I print out all the file names in the ```entries``` but I didn't find anything wrong with it. It seems that the program can find target files but can't display content of it. Is there any limitations on displaying large-size file in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I don't think there's a file size limit per se, maybe try with smaller files just to see? Also what if you try to display the resulting files outside of Python? I.e. use a text editor or something to inspect the content of the file after it's unzipped?